# Can I send a record like (multiple data items) to google analytics and analyse with any of these data?

Tags: google-analytics

From backend java spring application, I need to send the following record per a specific api call to google analysitcs:

user_name,IP,time,...etc

Then I need to analyse data using one of these data (user_name,IP,time,...etc).

Can I utilize google analytics in that? or even is there any other cloud services to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could but you can't, that's because **Analytics customers are prohibited from sending personal information to Google**:

> The Analytics terms of service, which all Analytics customers must adhere to, prohibits sending personally identifiable information (PII) to Analytics (such as names, social security numbers, email addresses, or any similar data), or data that permanently identifies a particular device (such as a mobile phone’s unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset). Learn more about how to avoid sending PII. **Your Analytics account could be terminated and your data destroyed if you use any of this information**.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en